Can't Convert From Server Now DateTime to UTC -11
I'm trying to convert a Datetime.Now to UTC -11
TimeZoneInfo info = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(x => x.BaseUtcOffset.ToString() == "-11:00:00"); 
 try
 {
     DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
     DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, info);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }

The Exception Throwing is:
'The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, when the Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be TimeZoneInfo.Local.
Parameter name: sourceTimeZone'
i'm not founding how to fix it
with:
localTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(localTime, DateTimeKind.Local);

nothing changes

Why don't you just use DateTime.UtcNow ?

You may want to work with DateTimeOffset instead.

Hi, i end up using
DateTime localTime = DateTime.UtcNow; localTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(localTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified); DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime, info);
to resolve it. Thanks everyone

Give this a try:
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC-11");
DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(now, targetTimeZone);

